# Wait until event has finished

Tags: c#, asp.net

Trying to call this class-method (Invoke) from Ajax. The Method "StartLoginSignRequst" will fire an webservice request. It will raise an event to get the response from the server. I'm looking to get the OrderRef-GUID, it's retrieved from the raised event, back to the webmethod initiated from the Ajax-Call.

well the return string from method "Invoke" is return before the event has finished, resulting in a Null value string. How to confirm event has finished before returning method string "_orderref" ?

```
public static string OrderRef{ get; set; }

[WebMethod]
public static string Invoke(string usrCode)
    {
        string _orderref = null;
        try
        {
            StartLoginSignRequst(usrCode);
        }
        finally
        {
            _orderref  = OrderRef;

        }
        return _orderref  ;
    }
   private static void StartLoginSignRequst(string usrCode)
    {
        ServiceClass serviceclass= new ServiceClass ();
        try
        {
            SignRequestType srt= new SignRequestType();             
            srt.usrCode= usrCode;
            srt.usr= "testtest";

            serviceclass.SignAsync(srt);
            serviceclass.SignCompleted += StartLoginSignRequst_SignCompleted;

        }
        catch (SoapException sEx)
        {
            //error handler
        }


    }
    static void StartLoginSignRequst_SignCompleted(object sender, SignCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {               
            OrderRef = e.Result.orderRef;

        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException tie)
        {
            //error handler
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does `serviceclass.SignAsync` return an `IAsyncResult`? If so you could return that from the `StartLoginSignRequst` method, and call `asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(…);` to block until the operation completes.

Comment: Is there a `serviceclass.Sign` that's not async?

Comment: @mason wow thx, how easy. Just avoid retrieving results in event by using non-async method. OrderResponseType ort = ServiceClass.Sign(srt);