# Loop - with Async event

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asynchronous

Trying to Request data from Web-service via Async call.

Started a similar [Wait until event has finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42119471/wait-until-event-has-finished) post, in this case i was able to use a None-Async method. This is not the case now. There is no None-Async method available with current web-service. So how would i go a head and determine if the event from the Event "RespService_Send_Completed" has finished before initiate / move on with the next row in the loop. If event is successful the return from the webservice is a UUID in "e.Result".

```
foreach (string id in uuid)
    {
        WebRef.ResponderService RespService = new WebRef.ResponderService();
        _uuid = id;
        RespService.SendDataAsync(id);
        RespService.SendCompleted += RespService_Send_Completed;
    }
```

The code works fine when calling method

```
public void InvokeSend(string[] uuid)
```

with one value in string[] uuid. But when array containes more than one the code will fail.

```
public class SendReciveSoapData
{
    private string _uuid { get; set; }

    public void InvokeSend(string[] uuid)
    {
        foreach (string id in uuid)
        {
            WebRef.ResponderService RespService = new WebRef.ResponderService();
            _uuid =id;
            RespService.SendDataAsync(id);
            RespService.SendCompleted += RespService_Send_Completed;
        }

    }
    void RespService_Send_Completed(object sender, WebRef.CompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Saving Response Data to database
        string SuccessID = e.Result;
        string TransactionID = _uuid;
        DataBase db = new DataBase();
        db.UpdateResponseID(SuccessID, TransactionID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by, calling the "InvokeSend" -method from the event. Then working through the array that was sent to the Class, removing "Current" uuid-value after each iteration. Until array is empty.

```
public class SendReciveSoapData
{
    private string[] UUID_array { get; set; }
    private string CurrentUUID { get; set; }

    public void InvokeSend(string[] uuid_array)
    {
        int len = uuid_array.Length;
        if (len > 0)
        {
            CurrentUUID = uuid_array[0].ToString();
            string strToRemove = CurrentUUID;
            UUID_array = uuid_array.Where(val => val != strToRemove).ToArray();
            invokeSend(CurrentUUID);
        }
    }
    private void invokeSend(string uuid)
    {
        CurrentUUID=uuid;
        WebRef.ResponderService RespService = new WebRef.ResponderService();
        RespService.SendDataAsync(uuid);
        RespService.SendCompleted += RespService_Send_Completed;
    }
    void RespService_Send_Completed(object sender, WebRef.CompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Saving Response Data to database
        string SuccessID = e.Result;
        string TransactionID = CurrentUUID;
        DataBase db = new DataBase();
        db.UpdateResponseID(SuccessID, TransactionID);
        InvokeSend(UUID_array);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `_uuid` private field is likely cause of your issue.

Specifically, the `foreach` loop is not going to wait for the completed event to occur before continuing to the next `id`.  The `_uuid` field will be overwritten with each iteration, and since the loop is going to be fast -- unless there are a lot (thousands) of calls to create, the loop will finish before any of the completed events are raised.  There is simply no way to know what value `_uuid` will be set to when the completed event is rasied.

Most likely the loop will have finished and `_uuid` will be the last `id` when all of the completed events are raised.

I would need to know more about the API you are calling to know for certain, but `xxxxAsync()` methods usually return a `Task<>`.  Regardless of if it is a `Task<>` or something else, save all of the return values in an array and remove from the array when completed.

Again, can't be more specific without more information about the API.